# What does "key" mean in Javascript Arrays?

Tags: javascript

I have seen something like this in javascript code:

```
array[key];
```

What does that mean? I know that you can access different values of an array with their index like this:

```
var myVar = arr[7];
```

But what does using the word "key" as an index mean? What does it do?

Comment: `var key=1,arr=['foo','bar'];arr[key]=='bar'`

Comment: The same as any other variables, `array[asdf]` and `array[foobar]` and `array[wafflesArePancakesWithBuiltInSyrupReservoirs]` all mean the same thing (but with differnet variable names of course).

Comment: There is nothing special about the name "key", it's just a variable name. Arrays are Objects, you can access their properties using [*(square) bracket notation*](https://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-property-accessors), just like any other object.

Answer (score 2):

`key` is just a variable that holds an array index.

This example:

```
var key = 7;
var item = array[key];
```

gets you the same value as this:

```
var item = array[7];
```

---

A more common use might be like this:

```
var proteins = ["chicken", "steak", "ham", "eggs", "tofu"];
for (var index = 0; index < proteins.length; index++) {
    console.log(proteins[index]);
}
```

Comment: I understand that, but do you know how to check to see if a specified value is in an array? For example, something like
`array.search("word");`

Comment: @user3055828 - That isn't what your original question asked at all, but you can find a value in an array with the `.indexOf()` method as in `array.indexOf("word") !== -1`.  `.indexOf(searchVal)` will return the index in the array where the item was found or `-1` if not found.

Answer (score 0):

"key" could be just a variable's name in addition to the example shown in the previous answer, a potential application is if you have an array where the elements are stored in a key/value pair pattern such as:

```
var table={key:"1234"};
alert(table[key]);
```

The above is a valid expression.//results to '1234'